# change selected background color cardview by DiffUtil

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

good time. Using DiffUtil, I want to change the color of the selected text and card view whenever any item is clicked.The code I wrote is like this, but it seems that notifyItemChanged has expired. Thank you for the more up-to-date.Help me write more efficient code.

```
class CategoriesAdapter @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    //Binding
    private lateinit var binding: ItemCategoriesBinding
    private var items = emptyList<ResponseCategoriesItem>()
    private var selectedItemPosition: Int = -1
    private var lastItemSelectedPos = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemCategoriesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder()
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])

        ///////
        if (position == selectedItemPosition) holder.selectedBg() else holder.defaultBg()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            selectedItemPosition = holder.bindingAdapterPosition
            lastItemSelectedPos = if (lastItemSelectedPos == -1) selectedItemPosition else {
                notifyItemChanged(lastItemSelectedPos)
                selectedItemPosition
            }
            notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    inner class ViewHolder :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: ResponseCategoriesItem) {
            //initViews
            binding.apply {
                titleCategories.text = item.title
                //card-view

                //Click
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    onItemClickListener?.let {
                        it(item.id!!, item.title!!)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        fun defaultBg() {
            binding.apply {
                bgCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Bright_Gray))
                titleCategories.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Raisin_Black))
            }
        }

        fun selectedBg() {
            binding.apply {
                bgCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Raisin_Black))
                titleCategories.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
            }

        }


    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((String, String) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (String, String) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    fun setData(data: List<ResponseCategoriesItem>) {
        val adapterDiffUtils = BaseDiffUtils(items, data)
        val diffUtils = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(adapterDiffUtils)
        items = data
        diffUtils.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

}
```

xml codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bg_card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_2mdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2mdp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_6mdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Bright_Gray"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10mdp"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/_8mdp">
    <!--title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_Categories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/Raisin_Black"
        tools:text="popular" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My desired user interface
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ResponseCategoriesItem is the data class i think, you can add one variable isSelected with ResponseCategoriesItem Data class and by default all are false. and Click with specific item do isSelected true with this position. and then Called NotifyDataSetChanged();